# Why is this SQL code sporadically producing orphaned records?

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, duplicates, orphan

Disclaimer: I'm not a SQL expert. I'm trying to insert records into a child table before inserting them into the parent table. (After saying that I'm starting to wonder if this is even a good idea.) The parent table record holds a reference to the child table record, and said-reference cannot be null. This necessitates me inserting into the child table first, then linking to the parent table during a secondary insert.

Anyway for some reason, this code randomly produces orphaned records in the IdentifyingData (child) table e.g., they have no entry in the FraudScore (parent) table even though they should.

Here's why I'm confused. In trying to resolve this issue, I started dumping the contents of the @tempFraudScore table into a physical audit table so I can see exactly what's going on during data transformation. When I switch the below code that inserts into FraudScore from @tempFraudScore to insert from the audit table, all the child records successfully get a parent record created. This makes no sense to me.

```
insert into IdentifyingData (EntryDateTime, IdentifyingDataTypeId, Value, Source)
select distinct GETDATE(), tfs.IdentifyingDataTypeId, tfs.Value, 'SSIS'
from @tempFraudScore tfs
where not exists (
    select id.IdentifyingDataTypeId, id.Value
    from IdentifyingData id
    where tfs.IdentifyingDataTypeId = id.IdentifyingDataTypeId
        and tfs.Value = id.Value
);

update tfs
set tfs.IdentifyingDataId = id.Id
from @tempFraudScore tfs
    inner join IdentifyingData id on
        tfs.Value = id.Value and
        tfs.IdentifyingDataTypeId = id.IdentifyingDataTypeId;

insert into FraudScore (EntryDateTime, FraudCriteriaId, AccountId, IdentifyingDataId, Score, Source)
select distinct
    GETDATE() EntryDateTime,
    tfs.FraudCriteriaId,
    tfs.AccountId,
    tfs.IdentifyingDataId,
    tfs.Score,
    'SSIS'
from @tempFraudScore tfs
    inner join FraudCriteria fc on
        tfs.FraudCriteriaId = fc.Id
            and fc.UniqueEntryPeriod = 0
where not exists (
    select fs.AccountId, fs.FraudCriteriaId, fs.IdentifyingDataId
    from FraudScore fs
    where tfs.AccountId = fs.AccountId
        and tfs.FraudCriteriaId = fs.FraudCriteriaId
        and tfs.IdentifyingDataId = fs.IdentifyingDataId
);
```

@tempFraudScore comes pre-populated with all of the necessary fields except for IdentifyingDataId; that has to be created by first inserting into IdentifyingData, then updating the variable table with the created ID. Below is the structure of the variable table:

```
declare @tempFraudScore table(
    FraudCriteriaId int,
    AccountId bigint,
    IdentifyingDataId bigint,
    IdentifyingDataTypeId smallint,
    Value varchar(100),
    Score int
);
```

Could someone please tell me what could be causing these orphaned IdentifyingData records? Should I reconsider how the relationships between these two tables are structured? I'm trying to make things so that once a certain IdentifyingData record is put into the system, it won't get duplicated; it'll simply be referenced by newly created FraudScore records.

**Edit**
Attached is a screenshot from the audit table that shows the progress of data transformation for a single value (the Value column is the same value for these records; I'm blurring it out for privacy's sake). Note that despite the message "Post-FraudScore Insert", the record in question was never actually inserted into the FraudScore table.

[image]

**Edit2 (2/6/2018)**: I've added the following code to the stored procedure in trying to troubleshoot this issue. I had a value (99999) that appeared in the _Audit table's Value column, but not the second table's Value column despite the code simply dumping all data into these two tables from the same source! I'm not sure if it matters, but this stored procedure gets kicked off from an SSIS package's Execute SQL Task with an IsolationLevel of "Serializable". That-said, I'm not explicitly using transactions anywhere in the code, and the TransactionOption for that Execute SQL Task is set as "Supported". I have no clue if this would have anything to do with the issue.

```
insert into FraudScoreIdentifyingData_Audit
select 'Post-IdentifyingData Update', GETDATE(), FraudCriteriaId, AccountId, IdentifyingDataId, IdentifyingDataTypeId, Value, Score
from @tempFraudScore;

insert into FraudScoreIdentifyingData
select GETDATE(), FraudCriteriaId, AccountId, IdentifyingDataId, IdentifyingDataTypeId, Value, Score, 1
from @tempFraudScore;
```

Here are the two tables' schemas:

[image]

Comment: where's the enclosing transaction?

Comment: @MitchWheat -- Pardon my ignorance but I'm not sure what you mean. Do I have a "begin transaction" statement?

Comment: @MitchWheat -- In looking this up, do you mean where are my BEGIN and END statements? This code is from a stored procedure, and there's only one BEGIN and END statement. Both are at the beginning and end of the stored procedure, respectively, while all my code including what you see above, is in the middle. Should I have more due to the complexity of the query?

Comment: Tip: When using `GetDate()` in multiple statements, e.g. within a stored procedure, one may avoid interesting surprises by getting a single value and using it throughout, i.e. `declare @Now as DateTime = GetDate();` and use `@Now` as needed.

Comment: I guess the last insert (insert into FraudScore) is the issue?. There are a lot of predicates and joins in here that will stop records being inserted. You need to go through these carefully. Can `UniqueEntryPeriod` or any other join column ever be NULL? You say these are parent child tables. Is the relationship one to many or one to one? What are the primary keys of each table?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid -- It's a one-to-one between FraudScore and IdentifyingData. And no, UniqueEntryPeriod cannot be null.

Comment: If it's an intermittent issue then it's probably data related so its not possible for us to work out the issue. It could be solved by just putting all the data in _one_ table

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid -- I've had to take a pause on this problem because my priorities have been shifted at work. But yes, one table would solve this issue. But the downside with that is that we could have duplicate IdentifyingData then. E.g., you could potentially have FraudScore records that have the same Value. That's perfectly valid, but I was going all architecture-astronaut on the database design; trying to eliminate duplicate data entry and keep the database size small. Funnily enough I didn't foresee the orphan issue.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid -- I'm looking at this issue again, and realized I wasn't correct in one of my prior comments. The relationship of FraudScore to IdentifyingData is many-to-one.

Comment: Can you clarify: each `FraudScore` (parent) has one or many `IdentifyingData` (child) records? This would mean that you need to insert into the parent _first_ to generate an ID, then carry that ID through to all child records. What is @tempFraudScore unique on? By 'orphan' do you mean records in  `IdentifyingData` have NULL values in their parentid field? I don't even see a parent id field in this table.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid -- FraudScore has a foreign key reference to IdentifyingData. There can be many FraudScore records to an IdentifyingData record. E.g., multiple accounts (represented by multiple FraudScore records) could be using the same address (the address, being recorded as a single record in IdentifyingData).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was a single delete statement buried in one of my large stored procedures that was written incorrectly that was causing the problem.

In searching for the cause of this issue, I also had a DBA sit with me and he identified a part of my SSIS process that was reorganizing indexes; but it was doing so as the package continued to run and populate all the necessary underlying tables (including the one with the orphaned records). According to him, reorganizing or rebuilding indexes on tables while simultaneously attempting to add or remove records to those tables could also cause this problem; although in my specific case it was the incorrectly written, single delete statement.

Answer (score 0):

Can't say what causing the problem.

```
Parent Table=FraudScore

Child Table=IdentifyingData
```

how they are related ?First you insert record in `FraudScore` then using output clause if you have more than one insert,insert record in `IdentifyingData`

But this is ideal situation to use `OUTPUT clause` even if problem do not solve because of this.

```
    --data type similar to IdentifyingData
declare @tbl table(Id int,Value int,IdentifyingDataTypeId int)
declare @CurrentDateTime datetime=GETDATE()

begin try
begin transaction

insert into IdentifyingData (EntryDateTime, IdentifyingDataTypeId
, Value, Source)
OUTPUT INSERTED.Id, INSERTED.Value, INSERTED.IdentifyingDataTypeId  
        INTO @tbl  
select distinct @CurrentDateTime, tfs.IdentifyingDataTypeId
, tfs.Value, 'SSIS'
from @tempFraudScore tfs
where not exists (
    select id.IdentifyingDataTypeId, id.Value
    from IdentifyingData id
    where tfs.IdentifyingDataTypeId = id.IdentifyingDataTypeId
        and tfs.Value = id.Value
);


update tfs
set tfs.IdentifyingDataId = id.Id
from @tempFraudScore tfs
    inner join @tbl id on
        tfs.Value = id.Value and
        tfs.IdentifyingDataTypeId = id.IdentifyingDataTypeId;

insert into FraudScore (EntryDateTime, FraudCriteriaId, AccountId, 
IdentifyingDataId, Score, Source)
select distinct
    @CurrentDateTime EntryDateTime,
    tfs.FraudCriteriaId,
    tfs.AccountId,
    tfs.IdentifyingDataId,
    tfs.Score,
    'SSIS'
from @tempFraudScore tfs
    inner join FraudCriteria fc on
        tfs.FraudCriteriaId = fc.Id
            and fc.UniqueEntryPeriod = 0
where not exists (
    select fs.AccountId, fs.FraudCriteriaId, fs.IdentifyingDataId
    from FraudScore fs
    where tfs.AccountId = fs.AccountId
        and tfs.FraudCriteriaId = fs.FraudCriteriaId
        and tfs.IdentifyingDataId = fs.IdentifyingDataId
);
COMMIT
end TRY
begin CATCH
if(@@trancount>0)
ROLLBACK
end CATCH
```